# values not updating with increment in i

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. Here is the piece of code I'm trying to understand. I'm incrementing `i` value changing the `name` and `id` in `img` then pushing it to array `data`. As show in output, value is same throughout the loop. why isn't `name` and `id` changing with `i`. I'm unable to figure it out. Need help?

my code is

```
var data=[]
var img={}
for(var i =0 ;i<5;i++){
    img.name="i"+i;
    img.id=i;
    data.push(img);
}

console.log(data);
```

ouput is :

```
[ { name: 'i4', id: 4 },
  { name: 'i4', id: 4 },
  { name: 'i4', id: 4 },
  { name: 'i4', id: 4 },
  { name: 'i4', id: 4 } ]
```

Comment: You pushed 5 times same object to array. Try `push({ id: i, name: i })` or move `img = {}` inside loop.

Comment: @csharpfolk Thanks! It helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code please it worked and tested :

```
var data=[];

for(var i =0 ;i<5;i++){
var img={};
    img.name="i"+i;
    img.id=i;
    data.push(img);
}

console.log(data);
```